# Can you use the pandas df.str.replace() function for multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I'm using the pandas `df.str.replace()` function and would like to remove multiple characters from the string.

I'm trying to clean up some transaction data in a CSV file using `pandas`. I have a column that is storing the amount of the transaction as an `Object` data type. Before I can change it to a `float` datatype, I need to remove the `$` character and any `,` characters from numbers greater than `999.99`. I've been able to do this one at a time; however, I'd like to know if I can pass in multiple values to clean it up.

2      8/20/2019                          Utah Valley Univ         UTAH VALLEY UNIV UVU PMT 1 908191  4,825.50

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace(r',','').astype(float)
```

I'd like to remove the `'$'` and the `','` character at the same time if possible.

Comment: `df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace(r'\$|\,', '').astype(float)`?

Comment: Dear @drewipson ,  you  can choose an answer as given below or comment if anything needed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking liberty to borrow the DataFrame from @Ian>

There is another way of doing it with `replace` method and withng `replace` using dict method to replace multiple value across the column..

```
>>> df
    amount
0  $25,000
1  $13,000
2  $65,000
3  $19,000
4  $15,000
```

It will simple remove the `$` sign and comma with null `''` values .

```
>>> df['amount'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True)
0    25000
1    13000
2    65000
3    19000
4    15000
Name: amount, dtype: object
```

Just to convert value to float use `astype`..

```
>>> df['amount'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
0    25000.0
1    13000.0
2    65000.0
3    19000.0
4    15000.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to steal @political scientist's comment and make it an answer with a little explanation.

Using some fake data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 100, size=(5,)), columns=['amount']).applymap(str)

df.amount = '$' + df.amount + ',' + '000'

print(df)

    amount
0  $42,000
1  $17,000
2  $77,000
3  $14,000
4  $80,000
```

We have `$` and `,` in our `amount` column. Using

```
df.amount.str.replace(r'\$|\,', '').astype(float)
```

We get

```
0    42000.0
1    17000.0
2    77000.0
3    14000.0
4    80000.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

Why? By default the `.str.replace()` method has the parameter `regex=True` which means it accepts regular expressions for pattern matching.

- The `r` at the front of the string tells the code to read the string as "raw"
- `\$` says to look for a dollar sign
- `|` is the symbol for `or`
- `\,` says to look for a comma

Using the `|` between the `\$` and the `\,` (without a space!) means to look for either and replace them both with what is present at the second parameter in the method (aka `repl`)

Here is a cheat sheet I found that explains other regex characters and how to use them: [Regex tutorial — A quick cheatsheet by examples](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)